# Proof $\Vert x\Vert_\infty \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq \sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_\infty$

Tags: analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we define $\Vert x \Vert _\infty := \sup_{k = 1,..,n} |x_k|$ (meaning that $\Vert x \Vert _\infty $ is the biggest component of $x$ according to amount)

How can one prove that

$$\Vert x\Vert_\infty \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq \sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_\infty$$

I have seen it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Properties), but there's no proof to it.

I know that using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality we get for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\Vert x\Vert_1=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|\cdot 1\leq
\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1^2\right)^{1/2}=
\sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_2
$$

but that doesn't help me.

Comment: which definition are you using for $\| \cdot \|$?  The Euclidean $n$-norm?

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Both your comments link to the same question. Did you mean to add a different link?

Comment: @MartinR Yes I did, thanks for pointing out the mistake. The other link was supposed to be [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662508/equivalence-of-two-norm-and-infinity-norm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\| x \|_\infty = \sup_{k = 1,..,n} |x_k| =\sqrt{  \sup_{k = 1,..,n} |x_k|^2 } \leq  \sqrt{  \sum_{k = 1}^n |x_k|^2 }$$

For the second 
$$\sqrt{  \sum_{j = 1}^n |x_j|^2 } \leq \sqrt{  \sum_{j = 1}^n \sup_{k = 1,..,n} |x_k|^2 }$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Vert x \Vert_\infty=l=\sup_\limits{i\in{1,2,...n}}\vert x_i \vert$

Note that $0 \leq l, \Vert x \Vert _2$.

Then $l^2 \leq \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \vert x_i \vert^2 \implies \Vert x \Vert_\infty=l\leq \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \vert x_i \vert^2} =\Vert x\Vert _2$

Also $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \vert x_i \vert^2 \leq \sum \limits_{i=1}^nl^2 \implies \sqrt{\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \vert x_i \vert^2} \leq l\sqrt n \implies \Vert x \Vert _2 \leq \sqrt n\Vert x \Vert_\infty $