# Concentration of the $\ell_2$ error of the empirical distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes values only in the set $\{1,2, \dots, m\}$ such that $\Pr(X = i) = p_i$ for all $i = 1,2, \dots, m$. Let $S = \{X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n\}$ be a set of $n$ i.i.d. realisations of $X$. We can then construct the empirical distribution  $\{\hat{p}_i\}_{i = 1}^m$ using the samples from $S$, where $\hat{p}_i = \frac{1}{n} |\{ j : X_j = i\}|$.

I am interested in the concentration inequalities for the random variable $Z := Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]$ where $Y = \| \hat{p} - p \|^2_2$, the square of the $\ell_2$ norm of the difference between the true and the empirical distribution. I have found results in the literature on the concentration of the $\| \hat{p} - p\|_1$, $D(\hat{p} \| p)$ and $\sup_{i} |\hat{p}_i - p_i |$, where $D(p\|q)$ is the KL divergence between $p$ and $q$. However, quite surprisingly, I haven't come across any result on the concentration of the $\ell_2$ norm. While it is possible to directly use the results for other norm for my case, it turns out that the resulting bounds are not tight enough for my case.

Any leads or references will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Note that if $F_n$ denotes the empirical c.d.f. and $F$ the c.d.f., and $i^{\star} = \text{argmax}_{1 \leq i \leq m} |\hat{p}_i - p_i|$, then

- $\|v\|_2 \leq \sqrt{m} \|v\|_{\infty}$ for any vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^m$, see for example here: [Equivalence of Two Norm and Infinity Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662508/equivalence-of-two-norm-and-infinity-norm).
- $\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_{\infty} = |\hat{p}_{i^{\star}} - p_{i^{\star}}| \leq 2 \|F_n - F\|_{\infty}$, since the worst case scenario is that $F_n(x_{i^{\star}}^-)$ was at a distance $\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_{\infty}$ above or below $F(x_{i^{\star}}^-)$ and then after taking the mass at $x_{i^{\star}}$ into account, the roles flipped.
- $\mathbb{P}(\|F_n - F\|_{\infty} > t) \leq 2 e^{-2 n t^2}$ for all $t > 0$, by the Dvoretsky, Kiefer and Wolfowitz theorem (see e.g. here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality#:~:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20probability,the%20empirical%20samples%20are%20drawn.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20probability,the%20empirical%20samples%20are%20drawn.))

By these three points (in order), we have, for all $t > 0$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\Big(\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2 > t\Big) \leq \mathbb{P}\Big(\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_{\infty} > \frac{t}{\sqrt{m}}\Big) \leq \mathbb{P}\Big(\|F_n - F\|_{\infty} > \frac{t}{2 \sqrt{m}}\Big) \leq 2 e^{- \frac{n t^2}{2 m}}.
\end{align*}

Furthermore, if you want the concentration about the mean, note that $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is concave, so Jensen's inequality yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2\Big]
&\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^m |\hat{p}_i - p|^2\Big]} \\
&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{n^2} \mathbb{E}\Big[|\sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{1}_{\{X_j = i\}} - n p_i|^2\Big]} \\
&\leq \sqrt{m \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} p_i (1 - p_i)} \quad \text{since } \sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{1}_{\{X_j = i\}}\sim \text{Binomial}(n, p_i) \\
&\leq \sqrt{\frac{m}{4 n}} \quad \text{since } \max_{x\in [0,1]} x(1-x) = 1/4
\end{align*}
and thus, by the previous concentration bound, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\Big|\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2 - \mathbb{E}\Big[\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2\Big]\Big| > t\bigg)
&\leq \mathbb{P}\Big(\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2 + \mathbb{E}\Big[\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2\Big] > t\Big) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}\Big(\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2 > t - \sqrt{\frac{m}{4 n}}\Big) \\
&\leq 2 \exp\Bigg(- \frac{n \big(t - \sqrt{\frac{m}{4 n}}\big)^2}{2 m}\Bigg) \\
&\leq 2 \exp\Big(-\frac{n t^2}{2m}\Big) \exp\Big(+ \frac{t}{4} \sqrt{\frac{n}{m}}\Big)
\end{align}
In particular, if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{t}{\sqrt{n/m}} = 0$, then for any given $\epsilon > 0$, we have, for $n$ large enough,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\Big|\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2 - \mathbb{E}\Big[\|\hat{p}_n - p\|_2\Big]\Big| > t\bigg)
&\leq 2 \exp\Big(-\frac{n t^2}{(2 + \epsilon) m}\Big).
\end{align}
This whole reasoning is valid even if $m$ is a function of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frederic! I have tried this approach and as I mentioned in my question, these bounds seem to be loose for my purpose. Results suggest that the denominator in the RHS is much smaller than the one obtained here. If these bounds are provably optimal, I'd love to see a proof or a reference.

Comment: No, it's not optimal, the constant $(2 + \epsilon) m$ could be improved, but I don't think you can get anything better than $n t^2$ in the numerator of the exponential, which is ultimately what should make the difference. What bound do you need ?

Comment: The bounds that I need to prove suggest that $t^2 \sim n^2/m$. Additionally the use of DKW totally makes it independent of the underlying probability distribution which I believe makes it lose adaptivity to the underlying distribution and thereby the choice of exponent is in some sense a worst case choice to guard against all distributions.

Comment: I don't understand what $t^2 \sim n^2 / m$ means, please post exactly the result you want, not some derivative statement.

Comment: I don't have an exact inequality in mind. I am trying to prove another result that uses this result and when I plug in the values in that question, these bounds end up being very loose. I will once again check my problem and see if I can come up with an exact version of what I want to prove. Thanks for your help!