# The Equivalence of the $2$-norm and infinity norm

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

How could I show that:
$$\lVert x\rVert_{\infty}\leqslant\lVert x\rVert_2\leqslant\lVert x\rVert_\infty\;.$$
I was able to show the right side but troubling with the left-hand side. What would be the best way to approach it?

Can I just write this without proving?
$$\lVert x\rVert_{\infty}=\max\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\big\{x_i\big\}\leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}=\lVert x\rVert_2\;.$$

Comment: Well, both inequalities can't possibly hold, because then we'd be able to deduce $\|x\|_\infty = \|x\|_2$, which is often not true. You're probably missing a constant factor.

Comment: Right hand inequality is not even true. How did you manage to prove it?

Comment: *Hint*: Try to prove that $\lVert x \rVert_\infty \leq \lVert x \rVert_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \ \lVert x \rVert_\infty $.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of equivalent norms is incorrect. One says that two norms on a Banach space $X$ are equivalent if there exist constants $C,D > 0$ such that
$$C\Vert x \Vert_1 \leq \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq D \Vert x \Vert_1$$
for all $x \in X$. I assume you are working in $X = \mathbb R^n$. In this case, all norms are equivalent and this result can be found in many places online (including [this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662508/equivalence-of-two-norm-and-infinity-norm?rq=1)).